# Unable to get conditional statements to work with Ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, conditional-statements

I am using the Validation plugin and and form plugin. I'm not sure why, but I'm not able to get conditional statements to work within the success or complete sections. Is this something unique to these plugins/ajax, or am I doing something wrong?

Here's a snippet of the relevant part of the code:

```
$("#agreement").validate({

        //. . . 
                success: {
                function(data) 
                    if (index_origin!=index) {alert("1");}
                    else {alert("2");}
                    },   
       //. . . 
});
```

NOTE: I had originally set index_origin and index outside of the validate function, but the problem persists even when they are placed under the submitHandler function.

Comment: where are you setting index_origin and indes?

Comment: Do you have enough knowledge of what you are using? Ajax, jquery-form validation??? no ajax involved in you example code, and success word in validate() function does different thing. see [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#agreement").validate({

        //. . . 
                success: function(data){
                    index_origin!=index ? alert("1") : alert("2");
                }
       //. . . 
});
```

Your success function was missing curly braces. Also, that if/then was formatted kind of strangely. Try a ternary instead.

Comment: Thank you. I had included braces in my code, but neglected to include them in my example.

Comment: Then I take it you still haven't found a solution?

Comment: No, I'm still not having any luck. It seems to ignore the if and else entirely.

Comment: Sounds like the success function is never firing.

Comment: Actually - are you using this plugin: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation? Doesn't look like it has a 'success' method.

Comment: kennis - The success function does seem to be firing. It still applies the part right after the "if" function as well as other instructions, such as removing classes. But it seems to ignore the "if" and "else" altogether.